# Remove first n elements of bytes object without copying

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I want to remove elements of a `bytes` parameter in a function. I want the parameter to be changed, not return a new object.

```
def f(b: bytes):
  b.pop(0)   # does not work on bytes
  del b[0]   # deleting not supported by _bytes_
  b = b[1:]  # creates a copy of b and saves it as a local variable
  io.BytesIO(b).read(1)  # same as b[1:]
```

What's the solution here?

Comment: I *think* you'd only be able to do this through ctypes in an unconventional way. Bytes are immutable, they don't allow mutation w/o creating a new bytes object.

Comment: This sucks.. But since I only need it at that exact point, maybe an unconventional way would be okay

Comment: Why is this requirement in place? If you elaborate maybe a different solution might be found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use a [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-bytearray):

```
>>> a = bytearray(b'abcdef')
>>> del a[1]
>>> a
bytearray(b'acdef')
```

It's almost like `bytes` but mutable:

> The `bytearray` class is a mutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256. It has most of the usual methods of mutable sequences, described in [Mutable Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable), as well as most methods that the `bytes` type has, see [Bytes and Bytearray Operations](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-methods).

Answer (score 4):

Using a bytearray as shown by @MSeifert above, you can extract the first n elements using [slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

```
>>> a = bytearray(b'abcdef')
>>> a[:3]
bytearray(b'abc')
>>> a = a[3:]
a
bytearray(b'def')
```

Comment: combine this with the del operator and you can remove bytes without copying